# Unable to build a project on eclipse luna using swtbot

Tags: eclipse, swtbot

I am Running swtbot Test cases on eclipse luna.When I build a project manually it works fine.But when i try to build using swtbot (File -> context Menu -> Build Configuration -> build all) I am getting widget not found exception.When i launch eclipse through swtbot "Build all" option was not there in build configurations menu.What might be the problem ? 
Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be this?
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=463682
Bug 463682 - Build Configurations > Build All/Clean All/Build Selected... disabled